# DataContext Inheritance in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls

I have a Silverlight application. This application has a `UserControl`. This `UserControl` has a view model of a type we will call `ParentViewModel` assigned to its `DataContext`. In addition, this `UserControl` has two child `UserControl` elements. Each of these `UserControl` elements has a view model of a type we will call `ChildViewModel` assigned to its `DataContext`.

When a user clicks a button in on of the child `UserControl` elements, I want it to effect the second child `UserControl`. I have this working.

My problem is:  my `ParentViewModel` has a property that I want to bind to in each of my child `UserControl` elements. How do I bind to a property in my `ParentViewModel`? I always thought that a `DataContext` propagated through a tree. But it seems that I'm wrong.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make hierarchy from view models. Each child view model contains reference on parent. F.i.

```
public class ChildViewModel1 :...
{
public ChildViewModel1(ParentViewModel parentViewModel)
{
_parentViewModel = parentViewModel;
}
private ParentViewModel _parentViewModel;
public ParentViewModel ParentViewModel {get {return _parentViewModel; }}
}
```

in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding ParentViewModel.NeededProperty}/>
```